# Incorrect use of a Global variable in Python?

Tags: python, global-variables

I have inconsistent values returned for my global variable. I would be grateful for some guidance.

I have a list screen that can be in order of username, surname or forename. Via pagination it will list a few at a time then I can either next/last page or prev/first page. If I change from one criteria to another then it takes me straight to page 1 of the list, otherwise it provides the next/last/prev/first as required. For the page to remember the order (username/forename/surname) I save it in a Global variable member_filter_criteria.

On my PC this works fine with the code below, when I upload to Heroku then the member_filter_criteria value randomly changes from page to page. You can witness this in my running application:first login as Janice (password 'cat') at https://clubmanager-2020ad.herokuapp.com/auth/login?next=%2Findex, then enter  https://clubmanager-2020ad.herokuapp.com/testmembers.

I suspect I'm using or referencing the global parameter incorrectly but can someone tell me the correct way to do so.

The relevant code:

1) top of my routes.py file, just after the imports

```
...

member_filter_criteria = "Surname"
like = '%'
....
```

2 The def within routes.py is:

```
@bp.route('/testmembers/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def testmembers():
    # I need to retrieve the value of member_filter_criteria and like from the last call to this def
    #  This is why I have declared them as global

    global member_filter_criteria
    global like

    def printC(answer):
        return "\n{:0.2f}.\n".format(answer)

    form = MemberForm()
    form.fieldtype.choices = [('--', '--'), ('User Name', 'User Name'), ('Forename', 'Forename'),
                              ('Surname', 'Surname')]
    user = Users.query.filter_by(username=current_user.username).first_or_404()
    strbal = printC(user.balance / 100)
    club = Club.query.filter_by(clubnum=current_user.club).first_or_404()
    clubname = club.clubname
    todaydate = date.today()

    # If a new query we must set the pagination page to 1 at the end of this def
    #   Otherwise we use the current page number
    newquery = 'No'
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newquery = 'Yes'
        like = form.searchletter.data.upper() + '%'
        if form.fieldtype.data == 'User Name':
            member_filter_criteria = 'User Name'
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.username.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.username.asc())
        if form.fieldtype.data == 'Forename':
            member_filter_criteria = 'Forename'
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.forename.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.forename.asc())
        if form.fieldtype.data == 'Surname':
            member_filter_criteria = 'Surname'
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.surname.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.surname.asc(), Users.forename.asc())

        if form.fieldtype.data == '--':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.forename.like(like)) \
                .order_by(Users.surname.asc(), Users.forename.asc())
    else:
        form.fieldtype.data = member_filter_criteria
        if like == '%%':
            like = '%'
        form.searchletter.data = like
        if member_filter_criteria == '':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).order_by(Users.surname.asc(), Users.forename.asc())
        if member_filter_criteria == 'User Name':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.username.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.username.asc())
        if member_filter_criteria == 'Forename':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.forename.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.forename.asc())
        if member_filter_criteria == 'Surname':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.surname.like(like)).order_by(
                Users.surname.asc(),
                Users.forename.asc())
        if member_filter_criteria == '--':
            users_list = Users.query.filter_by(club=club.clubnum).filter(Users.forename.like(like)) \
                .order_by(Users.surname.asc(), Users.forename.asc())

    paginator = Paginator(users_list, club.items_per_page)
    if newquery == 'Yes':
        page = 1
    else:
        page = request.args.get('page', type=int)

    paginatelist = paginator.get_page(page)
    return render_template('member.html', title=_('Members'),
                           club=club, paginator=paginator, paginatelist=paginatelist,
                           form=form)
```

3 The form in forms.py (to change filter criteria is):

```
class MemberForm(FlaskForm):
    searchletter = StringField(_l('Choose One or more letters of name') )
    fieldtype = SelectField(_l('Search on: User Name<br>User Forename<br>User Surname'))
    submit = SubmitField(_l('Submit'))
```

4 The HTML screen is:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% import 'bootstrap/wtf.html' as wtf %}

{% block app_content %}
    <h1>{{ _('Member details')}} </h1>
    {% if current_user.adminuser == 'Yes' or current_user.coach == 'Yes' or
      current_user.treasurer == 'Yes' or current_user.sessionmanager ==  'Yes' %}
      {% if form %}
        {{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}
      <br>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
<table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>User Number</th>
        <th>Forename</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Member Type</th>
        <th>Balance</th>
        <th>Current<br>Member</th>
        <th>Member<br>Expires</th>
        <th>Registered<br>Member</th>

   <!--     <th>Administrator</th>
        <th>Coach</th>
        <th>Activity <br> Manager</th>
        <th>Treasurer</th> -->
        </tr>
    {% for user in paginatelist %}
        {% include '_user.html' %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% include '_paginate.html' %}

</table>
    {% include '_paginate.html' %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: The simple answer is: don't use global variables, especially not in web applications, where remembering state on the server is a really bad idea - after all, you can't be sure the next request will come from the same client and, as your application scales, whether it will be the same server responding to the next request. Include the value in the request and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Grismar, the multi threading point makes total sense, I will instead add a database column on the user to provide their state

Answer (score 0):

Grismar pointed me in the right direction - don't use Global variables in web applications because they are stateless and it is impossible to know which thread will pick up the request.